# Why cannot JAR find resources?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have two classes (`Play` and `editor`). `editor` uses `Play`. `Play` uses some external files. I imported them into Eclipse in order to address them straight (as you can see on the first screenshot).
[image]
I want JAR to be able to contain these files withing and be able to work with (import) them. Is that possible? What options should I choose while exporting project to JAR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `.wav` files from within a jar then instead of doing `String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");` and then loading the wav files from there, try doing something like :

```
InputStream stream = Play.class.getResourceAsStream("/result.wav");
```

From **[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html)**, it seems that `AudioSystem` does have an overloaded `getAudioInputStream` which accepts an `InputStream` instead of a `File` object (as in your code). So you could have something like :

```
public class Play{
    public AudioInputStream find(String s) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException{
        // Probably some try catch over the next statement to log the error if `result.wav` is not found.
        InputStream stream = Play.class.getResourceAsStream("/result.wav");
        return AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(stream); 
    }
}
```

For the above to work all your `*.wav` files must be copied to a source folder so that they are present on the classpath. To do that you could move *.wav into `sint/src` to start with (and then into a proper `wav` folder later on if needed). That would put them in the root of the classpath `/` and allow them to be referred to like so : `/result.wav` , `/x_SECOND.wav` etc.

### Working Code

Here is a bit of working code to test out `AudioInputStream` from **[here](https://github.com/ajorpheus/stack-overflow/blob/master/src/A.java)** :

```
public class A {    
    @Test
    public void testAudioInputStream() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
        InputStream stream = A.class.getResourceAsStream("/result.wav");
        System.out.println(stream != null);
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(stream);
        System.out.println(audioInputStream != null);
    }    
}
```

The above code worked fine for me and I got two `true` in the console.

#### GIT Hub Repo with Test project

You should be able to import the project in **[this](https://github.com/ajorpheus/stack-overflow/zipball/master)** zip and see the code working.

### Do you need a 'Fat Jar' ?

A bit off-topic, but if you need to build a  `fat jar` that includes all the jars needed by your project to run and is a single executable then try using http://fjep.sourceforge.net/ plugin to build a fat jar.

You can export a java project containing jars using the `File -> Export -> Other -> One Jar Exporter`. The jar that's thus built is an executable jar and needs nothing else to run.

Comment: so if i put all these `wav` files into the `scr` directory, along with `Play.java`, I will be able to address them directly?

Comment: Yup. However, not directly as `File` objects but rather as Resources on the Classpath. I have updated my answer with what your `find` function would look like after the change.

Comment: `AudioInputStream main = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Play.class.getResourceAsStream("blank.wav"));` produces an error `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Obviously it couldn't find the file. Are you sure this method is valid?

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze Try with `Play.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("blank.wav"))`

Comment: You have to have a `/` in the beginning of the path. Did you get a chance to checkout the GITHUB zip I pointed you towards ? That's actual working code ! All you need to do is download the zip, extract it and import to Eclipse to see it working.

Try `/blank.wav` instead of just `blank.wav`.

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze, when using getResourceAsStream("the_resource") the resource must be on the class path and is relative to the class you are calling getResourceAsStream on. For example, if you have class A in package x.y.z and you have resource B.wav in /wav directory you could call `A.class.getResourceAsStream("../../../wav/B.wav")` or `A.class.getResourceAsStream("/wav/B.wav")`

Comment: just as an option: is it possible to store all these .wav-s in some array as AudioInputStream-s at compile-time?

Comment: That my friend is a different question altogether :). Might be better if you raise it as a separate one and close this question. This is just so that the question is not lost in comments and is open to answers from other members of the SO community.